# Tagging Interfaces in Java

Tags: java, interface

What are tagging interfaces and what are they used for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because sometimes, it really makes sense if some property of a type can be used as a type itself - `Serializable` comes to mind. If I make a method like this:

```
public void save(Object data){ ... }
```

... you don't really know how that `data` will be saved. VM serialization? Bean property serialization? Some homebrewed scheme? Whereas if you write it like this:

```
public void save(Serializable data){ ... }
```

... it is quite clear (if only the designer of `ObjectOutputStream` had used this possibility!). Sometimes it makes sense to use annotations when you want to add meta-data to types, but in this case, I'd argue for a tagging interface.

Comment: `save(Object data)` vs `save(Serializable data)`, sorry to be dense but from it I still don't really know how that data will be saved, as there is no enforcement on how to serialize from Serializable Interface at all. I believe that 99.9999% of the classes should `implements` Serializable and Cloneable Interface, but I seldom see anyone doing that (just by my casual observation though).

Comment: What I was trying to say has been summarized much better [here](https://programming.guide/java/marker-interface.html) -- it _"violates the principle of least astonishment"_, as _"the primary purpose of an interface is to establish a contract of communication. Since an empty interface is a contract that says nothing, it's at first glance quite useless. Some argue that marker interfaces aren't actual interfaces at all.
"_

Comment: @xpt the advantage of a signature like `void save(Serializable data)` is that it will not surprise you by throwing an exception saying "you passed me something which isn't serializable", which can happen when things haven't opted in to serialization (and opting in is a good idea). And Java's serialization mechanism _is_ well-defined, although you can debate the merits of automagic stuff like this (I think we all can agree that Java's serialization was a mistake).

Answer (score 6):

A tagging interface typically has some magic associated with it: either directly built into the VM, or using reflection. Because the magic could technically apply to any class, you use the tagging to indicate that you thought well about the magic and whether it applies to your class.

Comment: Is it? Seems to me that extending a tagging interface can provide type-checking at compile-time for methods that only accept objects whose type is an extension of the tagging interface. Look at EventListenerList.add, for example.

Answer (score 5):

The question of marker interfaces vs annotations is discussed in Bloch's "Effective Java", and part of that section is available on google books [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA179&lpg=PA179&dq=bloch+%22marker+interfaces%22&source=bl&ots=yXHfNnq0P_&sig=sR69qRthbEJnQnWMxa_ZN7LLbgE&hl=en&ei=NIqKSu_qPJHQjAfY-dBn&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1)

Comment: +1 - Bloch, as usual, sums it up nicely and answers my comment/question on @Mnementh's answer.

Comment: Would someone summarize please, as I'm not able(/allowed) to preview page 179, and a link without summarization is not the proper way to answer on SO sites. CC: @NickHolt.

Comment: @xpt basically, interfaces only apply at the type level limiting where they can be used as markers, as where annotations can apply to pretty much anything - classes, interfaces, methods, arguments, etc.  Annotations can also contain compile-time state in addition to being a marker, while interfaces can't.  However it's more cumbersome to check for an annotation than an interface.  Finally, Java didn't always have annotations, prior to their introduction all you had was a marker interface.

Answer (score 1):

It was used to mentioned some property of a class (like Serializable shows, that the class is allowed to serialize). Now annotations could do this job.

Comment: @skaffman: is it anything other than it being harder to check for an annotation than an interface that makes you say 'annotations are not a replacement for marker interfaces'?

Comment: One can annotate code other than classes. One can also use annotations with arguments.  Take the JSR 305 `@ScriptAssert` validation annotation, for example.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers marker interfaces can also be used to specify additional properties of a class that is not inherited by some other already-implemented interface. One example of this would be the interface [RandomAccess](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html). It denotes a collection that can be accessed randomly without loss of performance and does not have to be accessed via an iterator to achieve that performance.

Comment: `RandomAccess` seems to me was introduced as a duct tape fix -- _"**Note**: Since `RandomAccess` is intended specifically for lists, an alternative approach would have been to simply add a `boolean providesRandomAccess()` method to the `List` interface. However, at the time `RandomAccess` was introduced this was not an option, since `List` was already around, and adding methods to an interface is not a backward compatible change. Had this feature been introduced today on the other hand, a default method could have been a good alternative."_, as per https://programming.guide/.

Answer (score 0):

You can tag your class with a tagging interface to say to your fellow developer and consumer of your class that you explicitely support that functionality. Think of Serializable; someone who needs to persist a Session and uses serialization to do that can safely use an object of your class.

It can be further used in reflection; nowadays it is common to use annotations to do this but in the olden days you can inspect a class, check whether it implements a certain interface (like DAO) and if so, process the object further (I'm thinking about the Entity annotation here).

Answer (score 0):

tagging interfaces are interfaces with no abstract methods inside , they are used to add a data type for the class which implements them and to be a parent interface for other interfaces ( especially with multiple inheritance in interfaces )

```
public interface name {} 
public interface john1 {} 
public interface john2 {}
public interface Demo extends john1 , john2 , name  {}
```

** when JVM  sees the name interface , it will find out that the Demo will exert a specific cenario .

Answer (score 0):

I would also add you can use tagging interfaces to restrict ownership of an instance:

```
interface IFlumThing;
interface IFlooThing;

class BaseThing {...}

class FlumThing extends BaseThing implements IFlumThing {};
class FlooThing extends BaseThing implements IFlooThing {};

class Flum {
   addThing(IFlumThing thing){...};
}

class Floo {
   addThing(IFlooThing thing){...};
}
```